# how to subscribe to a SNS topic on my ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've created an event associated with my bucket s3 and I would like my ec2 instance to subscribe on it.
I'm new to this technology and I do not know how to write down subscription code.
I have a python API on my ec2 that I want to run when a SNS message will be pubblish

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Receiving SNS notifications through HTTP is not a one step process. There are API requirements which have to be met, before SNS delivers any messages to that endpoint.

AWS does provide a step-by-step guide on how to build such an HTTP endpoint.

see [Sending Amazon SNS Messages to HTTP/HTTPS Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html)